# PHP if/else shorthand multiple executions

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, shorthand

In Javascript we can do this by following code:

```
function test(a) { 
  a && (console.log("somthing"), executeOtherFunction()); 
}
```

this code above is shorthand of:

```
function test(a){
  if(a){
    console.log("something");
    executeOtherFunction()
  }
}
```

Is possible to get this working for PHP?

I don't mean that use `console.log` in PHP, just want use same thing in PHP.

Comment: Why not just `console.log('first','second')`? And what do you want to do in PHP? Cause PHP doesn't have `console.log`.

Comment: You can do `$a ? action : action`

Comment: `echo $a != false ? 'first' : 'second'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks this works in PHP.

```
function test(a) { 
  a && (console_log("somthing") xor executeOtherFunction()); 
}
```

I think PHP is able to convert everything to bool without errors.

Comment: +1 - `xor` must evaluate both sides to determine the result, and everything can either be truthy or falsy and therefore cast to boolean.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, there is also *short-circuit* in condition evaluation.
With an `AND` (or `&&`), the evaluation will stop as soon as a `false` value is encountered.

But, the comma `,` operator is not supported by PHP. So, you can't execute two expressions by separating them with a `,`. It is only allowed, as a syntactic sugar, in a for loop:

```
for ($a = 2, $b = 4; $a < 3; $a++)
           ^
```

This construction is also often used with `or` keyword:

```
someAction() or log("someAction() execution failed");
```

This will log the error only if `someAction()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As Guillaume Poussel said, PHP knows short circuit in condition evaluation, but not chaining of code blocks via `,`.

If you are willing to *really abuse* PHP's weak typing system, you could use something like this:

```
if ($a && function1() . function2() ) ;
                      ^ concatenate the results of the functions as strings
```

obviously this would only work if you don't need the return values of the functions.

**disclaimer**: I don't recommend the use of this in production code, but it is an interesting thought experiment

Comment: It looks the `.` operator may have problems with objects without `__toString()` method.

Comment: sure, this is quite dirty. It would not crash, though: an object without a user defined `__toString()` method will be converted to the string `'object'`